# How to hide editor tabs in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have set *Tab Placement: *None**  in the `Editor|General|Editor Tabs` :

[image]

But as shown the editor tabs do appear anyways:

[image]

So what is the correct way to hide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tab placement" is a setting for editor tabs.
On the second screenshot, tabs do not belong to the editor, but to open projects. You can force IDE to open projects as new windows (instead of tabs) in system settings:
[image]

Comment: oh yea - those are projects!  yea i'll want windows not tabs.  But i'd rather not change the macOS overall setting; is there an Idea-specific way to select windows not tabs?

Comment: Not now. Will be implemented in the scope of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65293. Feel free to follow for updates